# Number of the current week AS3

Tags: function, actionscript-3

I'm trying to have the current week number.

I've found this code :

```
 function getWeekOfTheYear(d:Date):uint{
    var firstDay:Date = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    var dayOffset:uint = 9 - firstDay.getDay();
    var firstMonday:Date = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0, (dayOffset > 7) ? dayOffset - 7 : dayOffset);
    var currentDay:Date = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate());
    var weekNumber:uint = (millisecondsToDays(currentDay.getTime() - firstMonday.getTime()) / 7) + 1;

    return (weekNumber == 0) ? getWeekOfTheYear(new Date(d.getFullYear() - 1, 11, 31)) : weekNumber;
    trace("week number is"+weekNumber);
}
```

Weird question but, how do I call this function in my code ?

```
getWeekOfTheYear(//what do I have to put here//);
```

Comment: Like this for example : `trace(getWeekOfTheYear(new Date(2016, 2, 29)));` ...

Comment: Why not just use [`DateTimeFormatter`  with week of the year pattern (`"w"`)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/DateTimeFormatter.html#setDateTimePattern())?

Comment: The trace will never execute because you return (and thus "end" the function logic) before you trace.